# 'No match found' is getting when run the end point url thet got from running mock service

Tags: service, request, transactions, response, blazemeter

In blazemeter I created a manual transaction which includes request url and response body. Then created a mock service for that transactions. Then I was running the transaction and got the end point. Copied the end point and paste in to the new tab. But response is not getting.

I tried many times. I should get the response when run the end point